# SQL Server : 2 servers with different database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a `database1` which exists on `server1` and I have a database 2 which exits on `server2`.

- Server 1 uses Windows authentication (and it cannot be changed)
- Server 2 uses SQL Server and Windows authentication or mixed mode (this can be changed)

I need to get the data from `server1` and display it as a **VIEW** in `database2` on `server2`. So The code to get that is this.

```
SELECT        
    Customer_ID, Customer_Name
FROM            
    Database1.Customer.dbo.Customer
```

I have created a vb.net application where I need to connect to database2 because this will be my primary database, When I try to logged in to database2, I can access it using the connection string below:

```
conn.connection string="Persist Security Info=True;User Id=xx;Password=xx;Data Source=Server2;Initial Catalog=database2"
```

But when I call the **VIEW** it prompts a user failed. Why because the authentication in database1 is Windows while my connection string is mixed mode.

How can I get the data from database1 and the owner became database2 so that it will not prompt a user failed? Or what should I do?

Thanks in advance. This is a new scenario from me. Help me guys.

Comment: Use two connection strings one with Windows Auth and one with Mixed mode. Or if you are calling the view in server1 directly from an sp in server2, maybe linked server under server objects is what you need. Just make sure that the account that sql server uses in server2 exists in server1.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, The puzzle here is I cannot set the windows authentication to mixed mode. What is the best practice in this cases. @F0r3v3r-A-N00b

Comment: If you create a linked server it will prompt you what type of authentication the remote server is using

Comment: Your select statement uses a linked server. A linked server has specific security attached to it. Can you script the linked server definition?